# Is it possible to use the sendFile response method in node + express to send to the client multiple images?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

I'm trying to loop trough all files of an image directory, but when i access the route from the client the images cross each other and i get this error:

```
RangeNotSatisfiableError: Range Not Satisfiable
    at SendStream.error (C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Javascript Projects\myproject\node_modules\send\index.js:270:31)
    at SendStream.send (C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Javascript Projects\myproject\node_modules\send\index.js:670:19)
    at onstat (C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Javascript Projects\myproject\node_modules\send\index.js:729:10)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:199:5)
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at SendStream.headersAlreadySent (C:\Users\Utente-XB\Desktop\Javascript Projects\myproject\node_modules\send\index.js:390:13)
    at SendStream.send (C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Javascript Projects\myproject\node_modules\send\index.js:617:10)
    at onstat (C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Javascript Projects\myproject\node_modules\send\index.js:729:10)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:199:5)
```

```
app.get(`/${SECRET_IMAGES_LOCATION}`, (req, res) => {
    fs.readdir(path.join(__dirname, "/img"), (err, files) => {
        if (err) return console.log(`Unable to open dir: `, err)
        
        files.forEach(file => {
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, `/img/${file}`))
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Why are you trying to send multiple images at once? Try only sending the one file that matches

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can send only a single file per HTTP request. It is the HTTP protocol. You access one URL and you receive one image.